ScriptEngine Javascript in Springboot with Java 17
I have to migrate a project from a previous version of Java to Java 17.
During the migration I faced an issue with the ScriptEngine to evaluate a Javascript expression.
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");
return null
So at runtime I had a NullPointerException.
Looking for a solution I found that now nashorn is in a separate library and I need to add the dependency
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjdk.nashorn</groupId>
  <artifactId>nashorn-core</artifactId>
  <version>15.4</version>
</dependency>

I tried it and now it works.
Then I found another guide that recommend to use graalvm:
graalvm.org
and I tried to replicate the instruction, but I can't reach the same result, like something is missing.
My project is composed only by this pom.xml:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven_central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

and a test:
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
class EngineTest {

    @Test
    void factoryTest(){
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        assertFalse(manager.getEngineFactories().isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    void test1(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByName("js"));
    }

    @Test
    void test2(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByName("Javascript"));
    }

    @Test
    void test3(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByName("JavaScript"));
    }

    @Test
    void test4(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByName("graal.js"));
    }

    @Test
    void test5(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByExtension("js"));
    }

    @Test
    void test6(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByExtension("Javascript"));
    }

    @Test
    void test7(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByExtension("JavaScript"));
    }

    @Test
    void test8(){
        assertNotNull(getScriptEngineByExtension("graal.js"));
    }


    private ScriptEngine getScriptEngineByName(String name){
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        return manager.getEngineByName(name);
    }

    private ScriptEngine getScriptEngineByExtension(String extension){
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        return manager.getEngineByExtension(extension);
    }
}

If I start the tests, all of them fail. What is wrong with this execution?

"all of them fail" is not a specific error. Share the actual complete errors.

There is not an exception: each test make an assertion and none of the assertion is verified: in every test the ScriptEngine is null

I see. Why are you using version 23?

In the graal vm guide the version is the same for both dependencies, like this: <version>${graalvm.version}</version>.
But there isn't an indication about what version I need to use.
23.0.4 is the maximum version that the two dependencies have in common

This is a case that the latest may not be the best. Graalvm 23 is scheduled for release on September 2024. I would recommend to stick to an existing long term support release. The latest LTS was 21.

Tried also with version 21.3.10 and it still not works

POM is missing artifactID of the project. After I added <artifactId>GraalVMTest</artifactId> tests started working halfway, meaning some names are not working for the script engine call but some of them are working.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>GraalVMTest</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
            <artifactId>js</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven_central</id>
            <name>Maven Central</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>

Print engine names like below
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
List<ScriptEngineFactory> factories = manager.getEngineFactories();
for (ScriptEngineFactory factory : factories)
    System.out.println(factory.getEngineName() + "-" + factory.getEngineVersion() + "-" + factory.getNames());

result below in my system
Graal.js-Development Build-[js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript, Graal.js, graal.js, Graal-js, graal-js, Graal.JS, Graal-JS, GraalJS, GraalJSPolyglot]

not all of them working. Getting with extension name is always returning null but js,JavaScript,graal.js is working

Find working example here.
